# Using proxies with TLS in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, tls1.2

I am currently trying to use TLS 1.1 with python requests. So far I've been using this snippet:

```
CIPHERS = (
            'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA'
        )


    class TlsAdapter(HTTPAdapter):

        def __init__(self, ssl_options=0, **kwargs):
            self.ssl_options = ssl_options
            super(TlsAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def init_poolmanager(self, *pool_args, **pool_kwargs):
            ctx = ssl_.create_urllib3_context(ciphers=CIPHERS, cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, options=self.ssl_options)
            self.poolmanager = PoolManager(*pool_args,
                                        ssl_context=ctx,
                                        **pool_kwargs)

                                        


    self.session = requests.session()
    adapter = TlsAdapter(ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1 | ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1)
    self.session.mount("https://", adapter)
```

It works fine if I run it without an HTTP proxy, but does not seem to work/create a TLS connection when I do set an HTTP proxy in my session, like so:

```
proxies = {
                'http': 'http://{}:{}@{}:{}'.format(user, password, ip, port),
                'https': 'http://{}:{}@{}:{}'.format(user, password, ip, port)
            }
self.session.proxies.update(proxies = proxies)
```

Any ideas on how I could get it to still work with proxies? I am not too sure what I am doing wrong/need to change. Thank you!

Comment: You said it "does not seem to work/create a TLS connection when I do set an HTTP proxy in my session" what error are you getting or what is the actual output as compared to the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the way the proxies are being set or updated. The current way isn't setting the proxy at all.

Instead of using this:

```
self.session.proxies.update(proxies = proxies)
```

It should be:

```
self.session.proxies.update(proxies)
```

https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies